# BGE - Can't move characters by holding down sensor key

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I started making a simple Blender Game Engine project in which I have movement sensors connected to my controller (a Python script). My script says:

```
if sensors["space"].positive:
    owner.applyMovement([0, 0, 4])
```

so basically it will go upwards at a distance of 4 on the Z-Axis. However, I can't keep going up by holding down the key. I have to repetitively tap the key.

How can I allow holding down the key in order to move?

Comment: you need to activate True level triggering (pulse mode) with your sensor in the logic editor, it's a button with label like this ''' and you will be happy!

Comment: When you use an AND controller and a motion actuator, you do not even need [true level triggering]